# Clojure .get and its difference to get

Tags: clojure

What is `.get` in clojure and what is its difference with `get`?
I know what `get` does but have never seen `.get` before.

Comment: `.get` is an invocation of a Java `.get()` function. http://clojure.org/java_interop

Comment: Why not post that as an answer, @zerkms?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's how you invoke a `.get` method of an instance/class passed as a second parameter.

Eg:

```
(.get foo) ;; invokes an instance method of a foo object
(.get Bar) ;; invokes a static method of a Bar class
```

while

```
(get ...) ;; invokes a clojure get function
```

References:

- http://clojure.org/java_interop